# could not resample from BGR24 to YUV420P in Xuggler

Tags: image, video, encoding, xuggler

I'm trying convert sequantial images to video file.
But, this source makes error in encoding video.

```
public class Image2Video {

private static final double FRAME_RATE = 20;

private static final int SECONDS_TO_RUN_FOR = 20;

private static final String outputFilename = "C:/image/myVideo.mp4";

private static Dimension screenBounds;

private static Map<String, File> imageMap = new HashMap<String, File>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFilename);

    screenBounds = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4,screenBounds.width / 2, screenBounds.height / 2);

    File folder = new File("C:/image");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    int indexVal = 0;
    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            indexVal++;
            System.out.println("file.getName() :"+file.getName());
            imageMap.put(file.getName(), file);
        }
    }

    for (int index = 1; index <= listOfFiles.length; index++) {
        BufferedImage screen = getImage(index);
        BufferedImage bgrScreen = convertToType(screen, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        writer.encodeVideo(0, bgrScreen, 300*index, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("Video Created");

}

public static BufferedImage convertToType(BufferedImage sourceImage, int targetType) {
    BufferedImage image;
    if (sourceImage.getType() == targetType) {
        image = sourceImage;
    }
    else {
        image = new BufferedImage(sourceImage.getWidth(),
        sourceImage.getHeight(), targetType);
        image.getGraphics().drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
    return image;
}

private static BufferedImage getImage(int index) {

    try {
        String fileName=index+".jpeg";
        System.out.println("fileName :" + fileName);
        File img = imageMap.get(fileName);

        BufferedImage in=null;
        if (img != null) {
            System.out.println("img :"+img.getName());
            in = ImageIO.read(img);
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++index :" + index);
            img = imageMap.get(1);
            in = ImageIO.read(img);
        }
        return in;

    }

    catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening becz your images are not of the exact same width, height.
Try to run the program with images of similar dimensions, you can see that the problem goes away.

You could convert your images to same width/height before feeding them to this program.